# Disable log chromium into Android Studio (LogCat)

Tags: android, cordova

When I open the webview cordova (app in release mode) The logcat show these logs I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] source http://.....

How Disable these logs into my application "I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] ,in Android Studio (LogCat)? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just override onConsoleMessage on WebChromeClient work for me ([reference](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/debugging#WebView)):

```
    webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage consoleMessage) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onConsoleMessage: "+ consoleMessage.message());
            return true;
        }
    });
```